Trim specific length from both ends of curve, for splines with varying length?
I have a single curve with many separated splines in it. I want to trim 1m away from the end of each spline, but I can't figure out how to do this using the Trim Curve node:

If I use Length mode, I can trim 1m from the start, but cannot use a single End length for both splines.

If I use Factor mode, I can enter numbers that work for one spline, but not all.



Option 1: Calculate Length per Spline
Use Length mode, and use the Spline Length node to get the overall length per spline, and then the Math node to subtract off the offset you want:

Option 2: Trim, Reverse, Trim Again
Trim the value you want off the front of the curve, use the Reverse Curve node to flip it around, and then use another Trim Curve to trim off the same value from the new Start:

